# Oven temps for cooking in enameled dutch oven

Tags: baking, temperature

What is the temperature needed to bake 1.5 lb boneless pork chops with 2 potatoes and mushrooms in an enameled dutch oven and for how long?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest an oven at 425 degrees Fahrenheit (218 degrees Celsius) and to use a meat thermometer for an internal temperature of 145 degrees Fahrenheit (63 degrees Celsius). It would probably take about 20-25 minutes if you sear the meat before putting it in the oven.

Comment: The thermometer is a good idea, but 63 Celsius surprises me. Even if this were the final temperature, it would be quite into "well done" territory. In reality, you have to take thermal carryover into account. In another dish, that would be about 5 Celsius, but assuming the chops are left in the Dutch oven - and people who bake them with vegetables usually leave them in the vessel - I would suspect much more. So I'd probably bake it to 48 or 50 Celsius and expect them to reach 58-60 for a medium doneness.

Comment: It's the USDA recommended temperature for pork's internal temperature so I didn't really want to recommend anything lower, but you're being a bit more reasonable.

Comment: Ah OK, the OP did not specify if they wanted a safe temperature or not.

Comment: 20 to 25 minutes is unlikely to be sufficient for potatoes unless they're cut rather small.

Comment: I noticed that during the exchange with rumtscho-- I'm thinking over how I'm going to edit my current answer to incorporate both of those issues.

Comment: I ended up using 325° for 90 minutes last Sunday.  Everything was tender and flavorful, but the boneless pork was a little dry? Is this indicative of over cooking or not enough fluids in the enameled dutch oven? Thank you for your advice. I will try next time.

Comment: @Tracey this is a very basic question, I would suggest that you read through our FAQ on how to cook meat such that it is not dry. See [What makes a moist steak or roast](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36854/what-makes-a-moist-steak-or-roast). Liquids have nothing to do with it, it is always the wrong combination of time and temperature.

Comment: Another potential issue: you need to make sure that this is a dutch oven without plastic parts. Plastic parts are usually OK up to around 350F, but not above that.

Comment: Another issue is that boneless pork chops are typically cut from the loin and contain very little fat. They tend to be naturally more dry than some other cuts.